# How do I allow users to buy multiple of the same in app product?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, in-app-purchase, product

I am trying to allow my users to buy in app currency with google play in app purchase. I cant seem to figure out how to allow them to buy multiple of the same in app product.

Comment: Need some clear explanation about your issue so we can sort it out clearly

Comment: Not sure how it could be any clearer.

Comment: I believe what you need is consumeAsync(). I'm not too familiar with Play billing my self but this might help https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#consumeasync

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62218448/7690376